# Did my subcounscious think of this joke in advance?

Tags: dreams, subconscious

Last night I had a dream where I was walking around an apartment building and I gt a message on a Whatsapp group of my old team at a company I used to work in. One of my friends in that team sent a phone number, and he said "You absolutely have to call this number."

I called the number, and got an automated voice saying "This call cannot be completed as dialed." This is a common error message in my country when dialing a disconnected number.

I was frustrated and I called that number again. Again I heard the line "This call cannot be completed as dialed." I waited a second, and then the same voice said, "You don't like it when that happens right? This is just one of the problems that happen because of poor people in the tech industry. Take Mark, for example. He used to get a lunch budget of 400 Shekels, but now he gets only 200 Shekels."

This was funny. After I woke up I wondered: **Did my subcounscious think of this joke in advance?**

**If the answer is yes,** I'm surprised because I really didn't know that it was coming. I could have not called the number a second time. I could have been distracted by the people who were making a commotion around me. If I didn't call a second time, I wouldn't have understood why my friend wanted me to call that number. In that case, would that joke have been left on the cutting room floor of my mind?

**If the answer is no,** then this is also surprising, because it was a very creative move.

Comment: I'm curious if this question is considered as a medical advice or not